# Unicode (Cyrillic) text in SVG in Apache FOP (XML)

Tags: unicode, apache-fop

(I don't know which FOP version I'm using. I only have API/HTTP access to the service. I'm asking.)

I'm making a PDF with Apache FOP. It contains SVG with `<text>`. Some text is Bulgarian/Cyrillic, inside and outside the SVG.

In a web browser, Bulgarian needs no encoding:

- In a `<table>`: `<td class="label">Спортуване</td>`
- In an `<svg>`: `<text x="153" y="91">Спортуване</text>`

In Apache FOP input XML, it needs encoding:

- Outside SVG: `<fop:block>&#1057;&#1087;&#1086;&#1088;&#1090;&#1091;&#1074;&#1072;&#1085;&#1077;</fop:block>`

  - Every character is encoded to a `&#0000;`
  - That works, **outside** SVG
- Inside SVG: `<svg:text x="153" y="91" >&#1057;&#1087;&#1086;&#1088;&#1090;&#1091;&#1074;&#1072;&#1085;&#1077;</svg:text>`

  - (Local namespace is `svg`)
  - Same exact encoding
  - Doesn't work =(

So the only part that doesn't work is text inside the SVG. Text outside works perfectly.

It's not the font. I can change inside and outside SVG fonts to `Times` ([the default](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/fonts.html)), and the same happens with the new font: works outside SVG, doesn't inside.

Web browser result:

[image: SVG in web browser]

PDF result:

[image: SVG in PDF]

PDF, outside SVG:

[image: Non-SVG in PDF]

My special spelling of Aesthetics (`aëstéthics`) does work in the PDF SVG. It's only partly encoded, since some characters are safe ASCII: `<svg:text x="436" y="218">a&#235;st&#233;thics</svg:text>`. The `&#1234;` encoded characters work, like they do outside the SVG for Cyrillic.

How do I add unicode `<text>` in SVG in FOP??

---

The 'new' version (1.1) on the same server, on CLI:

Without fonts config, no unicode works, all text is `#####`, inside and outside SVG.

With fonts config (TTF fonts copied from Windows):

```
fop -fo input.xml -c fop.conf.xml -pdf output-1.pdf
```

A bunch of these warnings:

> The following feature isn't implemented by Apache FOP, yet: table-layout="auto" (on fo:table) (See position 29:34)

and a few of these:

> Glyph "И" (0x418, Iicyrillic) not available in font "Helvetica".

but the result is very decent. The same as on version 0.9. No Unicode inside the SVG, but outside works.

---

Omg omg omg version 2.1 on a different server works!!

Even with weird java error:

> [warning] /usr/bin/fop: JVM flavor 'sun' not understood

If only version 2.1 was available on the right server, with http api acces...

[image: pdf output fop 2.1]

Comment: As I know (maybe I'm wrong), FOP uses Apache Batik (as a library) to convert any SVG file within .fo to PNG while rendering PDF files. Could you try to use Apache Batik separately to convert your SVG image with a font to any PNG image and what a result you will get?

Comment: @EduardTibet The SVG in PDF doesn't seem to be PNG, since all the text is selectable. Maybe the rest is PNG, but that's not the problem. Only the text is, which is still text in the PDF.

Comment: I just to tried to isolate a different parts of a complex system to get know where an issue appears. So that was why guessed about Batik.

Comment: It's not a bad guess =) Just incorrect in this case. Not many people pro at FOP apparently =( The hosting company isn't very willing either (understandably).

Comment: Can you just try to install a recent copies of the software locally and try to locate a problem? All parts are open source, so free for you from the point of licensing.

Comment: I have a newer version running somewhere, but I don't have an input XSL there, just an XML, so it's missing all kinds of config and styling, and NO unicode characters work! The 0.9 install I'm using is a very old hack that kinda seems to work, but no one knows how or why =) I'm waiting for answers from the original maintainer.

Comment: An what about try it locally? Fully locally? Have you any XSLT knowledge to write your own template to try all on your local machine? Is this file closed (NDA) or can you send it to me directly to check this out by myself?

Comment: I have no XSL file, that's the problem. I can run a newer FOP 1.1 on the same server, or FOP 2.1 locally, but I can't extract the config or XSL from the original setup, so I can't even get the same result, let alone a better result. I don't even know what the XSL should contain. All I know about FOP is it needs an input XML, I didn't even know about `.fo` or `.xsl` files being relevant. I can give you an XML input file, but I think it's as useless to you as it is to me. Want it?

Comment: After some more fopping about, the 'new' version (1.1) via CLI now produces the exact same output as the old blackbox version (0.9.5 probably) via HTTP API. The few unciode errors I see on the commandline are probably the same for both versions, but ignored via HTTP API. Still no Bulgarian text in SVG though. BUT now I can try version 2.1 locally.

Comment: @EduardTibet I've added more info in the question.

Comment: @EduardTibet Version 2.1 (local cli) works! See added info in question.